Cabinet replacement on built up floor
When we bought our house a couple of decades ago, the floors were carpet on plywood flooring on the bottom story. We had the carpet ripped up down to the cement and had 1 1/2 inch joists (sideways) and rustic flooring put over this. This was done for shock absorption due to back problems and floating floors were either not around, or not sufficient enough. Now I want to replace the kitchen cabinets, but the floor cabinets are "buried" approximately 2 1/4 inches under the floor.--If I decide not to replace the floor and just have it refinished, what should go underneath the new floor cabinets for support?

A 2x4 and 3/4 plywood is very close to the 2 1/4 depth of the floor. Adding that  will definitely carry the weight of the cabinets.
The big issue will be the footprint of the new cabinets. The depth of the toe kick is not always the same from one manufacturer to the other.  Rather than pulling your hair out to see which manufacturer/s fit, just pick the cabinets you like. If the toe kicks are good to cover the floor, great!  If they are a little shy, add some scrap wood to shim the toe kick covers out.
Since what you have now is practically no toe kick space, shimming to move the covers forward, if needed, should not be an issue for you.

A little extra molding may also solve any shortcomings on the toe kick.

The new cabinets can placed in the same footprint of the originals, in some cases, cover over it. This does limit what you can do in the way of a remodel, this would be the case if you choose to set them in the recess or build it up either way.
Where the recesses are, the floor can be filled in with not much concern. Use 2X laid flat, with the proper thickness of plywood to flush up to the existing.
In some homes where the flooring choice is costly, the flooring in not run under the cabinets and plywood or other filler is used under the cabinets.
